# Position Independent Executables and Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I have written a .c source code (in Eclipse) which is using libcap library to get information related to network traffic. Now i have created an executable binary by using ndk-build in Eclipse. I have pushed the created binary in libs/armeabi folder to /data/local/ folder of my android (rooted nexus 5, Lollipop) and tried to execute the binary. but android is throwing this error

> Error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

I don't know anything about PIE, Please tell me how to create a position independent executable.

Comment: Solved, just add these two lines in Android.mk file

Comment: LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I don't know anything about PIE, Please tell me how to create a position independent executable.

Position Independent Executable or PIE allows a program to be relocated, just like a shared object. At each run of the program, the program can be loaded at different addresses to make it harder for an attacker to guess certain program state.

You can compile and link a PIE executable in one of two ways. First, compile everything with `-fPIE` and link with `-pie`. The second is to compile everything with `-fPIC` and link with `-pie`.

If you are building both a shared object and a program, then compile everything with `-fPIC`. Link the shared object with `-shared`, and link the program with `-pie`.

You cannot do it the other way. That is, you cannot compile everything with `-fPIE` and build both a shared object and a program. For the details, see [Code Generation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) in the GCC manual.

---

One thing to watch out for on Android: building with PIE prior to 4.1 will cause a segmentation fault in `/system/bin/linker`. PIE was added at Android 4.1, and it crashes lesser versions.

Someone told me to supply a custom link/loader to avoid the problem, but I can't find the reference at the moment.

Also see [Security Enhancements in Android 1.5 through 4.1](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements41.html).

---

> Error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

Yes, that's a Lollipop feature. See [Security Enhancements in Android 5.0](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements50.html).

---

You can check if a program is built with PIE using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -l my-prog | grep -i "file type"
Elf filetype is DYN (shared object file)
```

The important part is `readelf` is reporting ***`DYN`***, and not reporting ***`EXE`***. `EXE` means it lacks PIE, and that should trigger a security related defect.

---

Related, see [Is PIE (Position-independent executable) for main executables supported in Android 4.0 (ICS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484814)

Comment: @jww I had compiled the linker without PIE. You can get it from here http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.com/2015/01/installing-python-on-android-50.html

Answer (score 5):

i know this is an old topic but this hacky way may save some people's time 
with a Hex-Editor , find the 17th byte, change the value 02 to 03, and that’s it!

Comment: Actually the PIE Exception was fixed with your given solution, but there was something wrong with the library that i was using. So conclusively your solution worked well!

Comment: this answer only solves the PIE error , but if you have 3rd party library which is dynamically linked to the Executable file it won't fix (it's not magic)

Comment: does not wokr for me. I get segmentation fault error