# Readelf reports program is a shared library instead of executable

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, clang

got this strange behaviour with standalone Android NDK r10e Toolchain (built with --toolchain=x86-clang3.6 switch). Environment variables for cross compilation **have been set** before running makefile, SYSROOT points to Android toolchain location, CXX equals i686-linux-android-clang++. Basically, I have a bunch of cpp files that I would like to compile to Android executable. Sadly, clang++ keeps producing .so shared library (checked with readelf - it is indeed shared object). Is there a special switch to compiler / linker that I have forgotten?

Makefile: (main.cpp contains main function)

```
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 -Wextra --sysroot=${SYSROOT} -march=i686
LDFLAGS=-lc -lc++_shared -L${SYSROOT}/usr/lib
SOURCES=main.cpp File1.cpp File2.cpp File3.cpp File4.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=test

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) ${CXX} $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
.cpp.o: ${CXX} $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean: rm *.o test
```

Comment: Are you sure you've copied your makefile here correctly?  To me it looks like this makefile will most likely give you _don't know how to build_ errors.  There should be a newline/TAB after the prerequisites / before the recipe, or else they should be separated by `;`.

Comment: @MadScientist That is right, TABs are missing here, probably cut it out when pasting.

Comment: Missing TABs is quite common on StackOverflow.  Missing newlines not so much ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> clang++ keeps producing .so shared library (checked with readelf - it is indeed shared object). Is there a special switch to compiler / linker that I have forgotten?

My ***guess***: `readelf` is outputting `Elf file type is DYN (shared object file)`, and you are interpreting that to mean a shared object :)

You probably did something like:

```
readelf -l test | grep -i "file type"
```

In reality, that's an artifact of Position Independent Executable (PIE) and `readelf` reporting.

The important part is `readelf` is reporting ***`DYN`***, and *not* reporting ***`EXE`***. `EXE` means it lacks PIE, and that usually triggers a security related defect.

---

PIE was added at Android 4.1, but it was optional. PIE is required for Android 5.0 and above. From [Security Enhancements in Android 5.0](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements50.html):

> **non-PIE linker support removed**. Android now requires all dynamically linked executables to support PIE (position-independent
>   executables). This enhances Android’s address space layout
>   randomization (ASLR) implementation.

---

Also see [Position Independent Executables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30498776/608639) on Stack Overflow. It discusses PIE and Android.

Comment: Thst's exactly what I did. What's more, after copying compiled file and running it from adb shell, it just works as expected. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction  :)